# Socket cannot be added to an array

Tags: python

i wrote this code:

```
HOST = "127.0.0.1"
PORT = 123

clients = []

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 123))
server_socket.listen()

def send_cmd(cmd):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(cmd.encode())
def handle_client(client_socket):
    clients.append(client_socket)
    message = "Hi!"
    client_socket.send(message.encode())

def accept_connects():
    while True:
        client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()

        threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket,)).start()
threading.Thread(target=accept_connects).start()
```

But because of the line clients.append(client_socket) in the handle_client function - the message "hi!" does not come. Help, please.

I tried putting clients.append(client_socket) into the thread, but it didn't help

Comment: **Never** use ports lower than 1024. You never try reading from the socket

Comment: Your diagnosis is incorrect.  The `client.append` line has absolutely no impact on the socket operation.  However, you don't need `accept_connects` to run in a thread, unless you are doing something else at the same time.  What does the client code look like?